# ComboBox Array Selection Display

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

Hi I created an array of student and grades my question is
How do I make it so if I select student Sam from index 0 and display the first array of his grades inside a combobox. What code do I write to tie them together. If you could help me I be very thankful.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] student = { "Sam", "Dean", "Nick", "Shara", "Kat" };
        cboStudent.Items.AddRange(student);
        cboStudent.SelectedIndex = 0;
        string[] S1Grade = { "Math: 78", "English: 56", "Bio: 94", "Art: 67", "Science: 64", "PE: 85", "Social: 89" };
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(S1Grade);
        string[] S2Grade = { "Math: 45", "English: 84", "Bio: 56", "Art: 67", "Science: 78", "PE: 45", "Social: 76" };
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(S2Grade);
        string[] S3Grade = { "Math: 68", "English: 34", "Bio: 98", "Art: 56", "Science: 55", "PE: 65", "Social: 56" };
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(S3Grade);
        string[] S4Grade = { "Math: 38", "English: 78", "Bio: 76", "Art: 67", "Science: 34", "PE: 45", "Social: 56" };
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(S4Grade);
        string[] S5Grade = { "Math: 88", "English: 84", "Bio: 56", "Art: 45", "Science: 56", "PE: 85", "Social: 89" };
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(S5Grade);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedStudent = cboStudent.Text;
        txtSelected.Text = selectedStudent;
    }
    private void cboGrades_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedGrade = cboGrades.Text;
    }
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off making a `Student` class and creating properties for their names and grades.

Comment: I have 2 combobox when I seletect a student is there a way that the second combobox display an array of they grade?

Comment: This sounds kind of like homework to me. Either way, the approach given by @JasonD is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this kind of approach:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] student = { "Sam", "Dean", "Nick", "Shara", "Kat" };
        cboStudent.Items.AddRange(student);
        cboStudent.SelectedIndex = 0;           
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboGrades.Items.Clear();
        cboGrades.Items.AddRange(Selecting(cboStudent.SelectedIndex));
    }


    private string[] Selecting(int index)
    {
        string[] arr = null;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: arr = new[] { "Math: 78", "English: 56", "Bio: 94", "Art: 67", "Science: 64", "PE: 85", "Social: 89" }; break;
            case 1: arr = new[] { "Math: 45", "English: 84", "Bio: 56", "Art: 67", "Science: 78", "PE: 45", "Social: 76" }; break;
            case 2: arr = new[] { "Math: 68", "English: 34", "Bio: 98", "Art: 56", "Science: 55", "PE: 65", "Social: 56" }; break;
            case 3: arr = new[] { "Math: 38", "English: 78", "Bio: 76", "Art: 67", "Science: 34", "PE: 45", "Social: 56" }; break;
            case 4: arr = new[] { "Math: 88", "English: 84", "Bio: 56", "Art: 45", "Science: 56", "PE: 85", "Social: 89" }; break;
            default: arr = null; break;//no correct index;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Is it any good?
And set comboBoxes property of DropDownStyle to DropDownList, so user cannot edit it, like (on loading time):

```
   cboStudent.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: No problem. Anytime mate.